# How to calculate distance between two points in a three dimensional coordinate system in R

Tags: r, euclidean-distance

I am trying to calculate distance between two points in a three dimensional coordinate system. I have two points: 1) 'Release' (x, y, z), and 2) 'Recapture' (x, y, z). I want to calculate the euclidean distance between these two points for each recaptured individual.

My imported data set in R looks like this:

```
|              | Rel_x   | Rel_y   | Rel_z  | Rec_x   | Rec_y   | Rec_z  | Distance |
|--------------|---------|---------|--------|---------|---------|--------|----------|
| Individual_1 | 231.114 | 177.002 | 17.329 | 228.288 | 178.908 | 17.243 | ?        |
| Individual_2 | 239.028 | 178.789 | 16.526 | 239.057 | 178.706 | 16.499 | ?        |
| Individual_3 | 212.109 | 210.142 | 18.791 | 212.300 | 208.693 | 18.372 | ?        |
```

I also want to add a column (distance) to report the euclidean distance between the two points 'Release' and 'Recapture'.

I have tried using the dist() function but I am not sure that my line of code is correct, e.g.

```
dist (data_set), method = "euclidean", diag = FALSE, upper = FALSE, p = 2)
```

When I run this line of code, I receive the following:

```
Warning message: In dist(data_set) : NAS introduced by coercion
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The `dist` function is specifically designed to create *distance matrices*, where you give it a single list of points and it gives you a matrix with the distance *between every possible pair of points* -- that's not what your input looks like, and it's not the output you want, which is why your `dist()` attempt didn't work.

Comment: Hi, thank you for clearing that up @Gregor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend just writing it out. Calling your data `data_set` we can adapt the other answer into a working one:

```
data_set$distance = sqrt(rowSums((data_set[, 1:3] - data_set[, 4:6])^2))
```

A safer approach would be to name the columns, not rely on the positional order:

```
data_set$distance = sqrt(rowSums(
  (data_set[, c('Rel_x', 'Rel_y', 'Rel_z')] - data_set[, c('Rec_x', 'Rec_y', 'Rec_z')])^2
))
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried running your suggested line of code that name the columns instead of relying on the positional order, and I keep receiving the following message: ' Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, distance, value = c(3.40976656092464,  :  object 'distance' not found '

Comment: Oops, my fault. I forget the `)` to close my name vectors. Should work now.

Comment: Not to worry, thank you very much for your help! The line of code now works!

Answer (score 2):

Split the data frame in two, separate for each point Release and Recapture, and then calculate the Euclidean metric.

For ex., assuming your data frame is named `df`, and the first three columns are for the first point, and the next 3 columns are for the second point:

```
sqrt(rowSums(((df[,1:3]-df[,4:6])^2))
```

Comment: `sum` won't work across rows - this will give a single number answer, not a vector of distances. Replace with `rowSums` and I think you're good

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I have just tried running the line of code that you suggested, and I have received the following message: 'Error in df [, 1:3) : object of type ' closure' is not subsettable'. What does this error message mean?

Comment: I have tried using rowsum instead of sum, and I have received the following message: ' Error in UseMethod("[") : no applicable method for '[' applied to an object of class "function" '

Comment: @MeghanLWharton People often use `df` to refer to data frames when answering questions on this site. You need to use whatever the  name of *your* data frame where this answer uses `df` (looks like you called it `data_set` in your question). Also make sure you replace `sum` with `rowSums` - notice the capial `S` in the middle and the `s` on the end.

Comment: Hi @Gregor, thank you very much for your help - 'rowSums' worked a charm!